# How can I slash through a formula?

Tags: support, mathjax

What is the MathJax syntax to produce a big slash through a formula? I've seen it used but can't find an example now.

Comment: It is probably better to ask this in Meta. It isn't about math after all.

Comment: Or http://tex.stackexchange.com

Comment: $\require{cancel} \cancel{\sum \! \! \! \! \! \! \large \int}$...

Comment: @draks... Here is a better version: $$\require{cancel}\cancel{\color{#01020b}{\rlap{\displaystyle\,\int}{\sum}}}$$

Comment: @Aðøbe touché...

Comment: Haha, very good, clever both of you ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's probably the `\cancel` command.

```
\require{cancel}
\dfrac{\cancel{9}}{2t}\cdot\dfrac{t}{\cancel{9}}
```

will produce: $$\require{cancel}
    \dfrac{\cancel{9}}{2t}\cdot\dfrac{t}{\cancel{9}}$$
For a slightly better appearance you can use the following code:

```
\require{cancel}
\dfrac{\color{red}{\cancel{\color{black}{9}}}}{2t}
\cdot
\dfrac{t}{\color{red}{\cancel{\color{black}{9}}}}
```

which produces: $$    \require{cancel}
    \dfrac{\color{red}{\cancel{\color{black}{9}}}}{2t}
    \cdot
    \dfrac{t}{\color{red}{\cancel{\color{black}{9}}}}$$

There is also the `\cancelto` command:

```
\require{cancel}
\cancelto{\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2+x+2}}{\sqrt{\beta+\alpha}}}{1}
```

$$
     \require{cancel}
     \cancelto{1}{\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2+x+2}}{\sqrt{\beta+\alpha}}}$$

Comment: I tried \cancel but the parser didn't know it. Now I see from your example that I needed \require{cancel} first! didn't know about that. Thanks! FOLLOWUP: Is this just how you use packages?

Comment: @MPW You're welcome! But I don't understand what you mean by your last question.

Comment: The equivalent of LaTeX \usepackage? Or maybe LaTeX already has a \require command? I'm a little rusty...

Comment: I learn something new everyday on math SE.

Comment: @MPW As far as I know (my LaTeX knowledge is very poor) the `\usepackage` and `\require` are equivalent. (I'm maybe wrong).

Comment: @AveMaleficum We all learn something new everyday on Math.SE :-)

Comment: I believe `\require` is a MathJax command. It fills roughly the same role that `\usepackage` does in LaTeX.