# How to make slash going through two digits?

Tags: support, mathjax

I want to try make it slash both of 2 digits.

For example if I do 
$$ \not{7}$$ it will slash that 7.

What to do for $10$ or bigger numbers?

Edit:
$\require{cancel} \bcancel{10}$

Comment: i want 1 slash can slash both numbers and not 2 numbers=2 slash

Comment: Closely related: [How can I slash through a formula?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12618/how-can-i-slash-through-a-formula)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\cancel{whatever}
```

Look [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for more references.

Comment: in some programs you need to do "\require{cancel}" before but in stackexchange you dont need

Comment: what you mean by in stackexchange dont need?

Comment: @mohamadmunzir mathjax is not used only by stackexchange, when using the commend "\cancel{ }" normally you would have to add "\require{cancel}" before. but in stackexchange, the site do it for you so you dont need that line

Comment: ok..it's worked...HAHAHAHHAHAHAHHA..thank you so much..you have my pleasure holo